# search for data by structure

Tags: metadata

Is there some way to search for data sets by structure, for example, I might want to search on the internet for time series data by time period, categorical data, share amount of total, or multiple columns of the above.  In particular, I want to search for (time series, category, share %1, share %2, share %3)

Comment: Searching for percentage, share or count attribute types would be useful.  I don't know how to do this at the UCI ML-repository

Comment: Ultimately, I want to search for data visualizations by structure as well.